# Validar campos con alpinejs y sumarlos con livewire en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

¿Cómo puedo validar 2 campos para que acepten solo números con alpinejs y hacer la suma con livewire en tiempo real?

Lo que tengo si funciona, pero el problema es que si el usuario ingresa caracteres que no sean números me genera un error:

```
<input type="text" wire:model="numeroUno">
<input type="text" wire:model="numeroDos">
{{ number_format($resultado, 2) }}
```

Backend:

```
Class Suma extends Component{
   public $numeroUno, $numeroDos, $resultado;
   public function render(){
      $this->resultado = $this->numeroUno + $this->numeroDos;

    }
}
```

Comment: Veo 2 posibles salidas: 1.  si usarás Alpine entonces es JavaScript y puedes buscar por ejemplo como escribir una regex que valide solo números o bien puedes usar las validaciones de Laravel para indicar que esos inputs solo serán aceptados cuando contengan números

Comment: ¿Nos mostrarías que has intentado al respecto?, así será mas fácil poder aportar una posible solución